# SailsJS on OpenShift with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift, sails.js

I'm trying to set up an SailsJS framework on OpenShift with MySQL database, but i can't get it to work...

If somebody could help with a small tutorial, i would be very gratefull...
How to correctly install everything that is needed and maybe how to create a simple model, controller, view and example how to enter some records to database and how to retrieve them from database and present them on web page. I think i can manage from there.

I'm a beginner at OpenShift, NodeJS, SailsJS and there isn't much on that topic on the web to find, so it would be great if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe too late, just leave it for future. 
For create controller, model part is quite easy to handle. A lot of youtube video is online.

About connection part, you will need to edit connection.js

```
module.exports.connections = {
  localMysqlServer: { ... },
  openshiftMysqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST,
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'dbname'
  }
}
```

And development.js

```
module.exports = {

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the default database connection for models in the development       *
   * environment (see config/connections.js and config/models.js )           *
   ***************************************************************************/
  models: {
    connection: 'openshiftMysqlServer'
  }
};
```

This should work!